# Android UI design: multiple icon sizes for multiple screen sizes

Tags: android, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.android, screen-size

I'm using Xamarin and Visual Studio 2012 for developing my application.
I have a main menu screen which contains 5 image views. I have created the following folders in the resources folder:
drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi
and I also created 4 sets of icons for these drawables with proper sizes. But when I test my application on nexus 7, icons sizes are the same as on nexus 4.
I also added these lines to manifest file:

```
    <compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have given icon size in density-independent pixels (dp) you can see the icon in same size across almost all the devices.

From the code you are instructing that your device should support only small, normal and large screens for mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi densities. Which is not relevant to your question.

Nexus 4  and Nexus 7 both fall under the category xhdpi, So both pick icons form drawable-xhdpi folder. So yo will see the icons same size in both devices if you have given icon size in dp.

If you want to create different sizes of icons for normal and large devices, create separate layouts which has different icon sizes in

```
res/layout
res/layout-large
```

folders

**Refereces:**

- https://design.google.com/devices/
  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html

Comment: thanks. what do you mean by "So yo will see the icons same size in both devices if you have given icon size in dp"? where this "dp" is set?

Comment: Do you mean launcher icon? it's standard size is 48dp * 48dp